# How to solve classcastexception while using List

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

```
public AmountDetail getAmount(String accId) {
    Optional<Acc> acc = accRepository.findById(accId);
    if (acc.isPresent())
      // this is fine and it's response type is -> AmountDetail
      return fetchDetails(accId);
    else if (!acc.isPresent())
      // here I am getting error while hitting the API
      return (AmountDetail) getSoDetails(accId);
}

public List<Values> getSoDetails(String accId) {
    List<Values> val = ser.getDetails(accId)
}
```

Values.java

```
{
    private String acc;
    private String email;
}
```

AmountDetail.java

```
{
    private String fieId;
    private List<DetailsConsumer> cons;
}
```

When I am hitting the API in postman if clause is working fine but if I want to check for else it is giving error. I feel casting is the issue here but I am not sure how can I return the values of else block.

Comment: Because a `List<Values>` is not an `AmountDetail`. If you're looking to push this out through a REST query, you likely either need a way to convert both values into a string form, or you need to return a common superclass (which in this case, might only be `Object`).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. You haven't shown the class declaration for `AmountDetail`, or the implementation of `ser.getDetails()`.

Comment: @Rogue: My guess is that `AmountDetail` *might* actually derive from `List<Value>`, but it's very hard to tell due to the incomplete pseudo-code instead of a [mcve]...

Comment: @JonSkeet I feel like we wouldn't see a CCE in that case, unless perhaps we're seeing a subtype/supertype of `Values` if `AmountDetail extends List<"Values">`

Comment: Again, we can't really tell without more information. I don't think it's worth speculating further. Let's just see if the OP decides to provide the info...

Comment: No AmountDetail does not extend List<Values>. Declaration of all the classes are given

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  // here I am getting error while hitting the API
>   return (AmountDetail) getSoDetails(accId);
> ```

For this line to compile, `getSoDetails(...)` needs to return something that can be cast into `AmountDetail`.

> ```
> public List<Values> getSoDetails(String accId) {
> ```

But `getSoDetails(...)` returns a `List<Values>` which cannot be cast into an `AmountDetail`.  You should probably do something like:

```
List<Values> values = getSoDetails(accId);
return new AccountDetail(accId, values);
```

You make the call to the `getSoDetails(...)` and then call the `AccountDetail` constructor to return the correct object.  I'm not sure if `accId` is an appropriate value for `AccountDetail` field `fieId` but you get the idea.